# Second countable space question

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

Let $X$ be a set of continuous function from the space $\mathbb R$ of real with the absolute value topology into itself. For each $f \in X$ and $p>0$ define

$N_p(f)=\{g\in X: |f(x)-g(x)|<p,  \forall x \in \mathbb R\}$

the family of $N_p(f)$ for each $f \in X$ and $p>0$ form the basis for a topology $\tau$ on $X$. Is $X$ second countable?

Let $Y=\{f\in X: f$ has derivatives of all orders at each $x\in X \}$

Is $Y$ a second countable subspace of $X$?

From the second part of the question I guess that $X$ must be second countable, othewise they will not ask stupid question like that. However, I know that the family of $N_p(f)$ for each $f \in X$ and $p>0$ form the basis for a topology $\tau$ on $X$, but I don't see any sign showing that this basis is countable.

Comment: Well, if $X$ were second countable, so would any subspace (including $Y$) be, so it would be "logical" that $X$ is not and $Y$ maybe is. Just from human logic.

Comment: It seems to be that $\ell_{\infty}$ would be embeddable into $X$ and this is not separable (so not second countable). (For a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, Weierstrass implies it is separable and thus second countable.)

Comment: can you tell me what is $\mathbb l_\infty$?  And I can't use anything from compactness or Weiertrass in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is not separable. For every subset $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ we can make a function $f_A$ that is $0$ everywhere except $1$ at each $n \in A$, with a small peak up from the base level of $0$ to make it continuous. Then for each $A \neq B$ the distance between $f_A$ and $f_B$ equals $1$, so all open balls around different $f_A$ (of which there are continuum many) of radius $\frac{1}{3}$ are all mutually disjoint and any dense set should intersect them all. And a space that is second countable has all subspace separable...

[Added] $Y$ is similarly non-separable, because we can make the peaks infinitely differentiable if we want.

Comment: are you using the definition of separable sets in Advance Calculus, which say $A$ and $B$ are separated set if $d(A,B)>0$?

Comment: You can make your peaks infinitely differentiable, so $Y$ is not separable by the same argument.

Comment: ok, are you guy using the definition $X$ is separable if it contain a countable dense subset? Because if you do, I'm not sure I understand your answer.